# Showing generalised eigenspace is stable

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra with $L \subseteq \mathfrak{gl}(V) $ ($V$ finite dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$) and let $I$ be an abelian ideal of $L$. Given $x \in I, \lambda \in \mathbb{C} $, I am trying to show that the generalised eigenspace $\ker((x-\lambda \text{Id}_V)^{\dim V })$ is stable meaning for all $y \in L$ and all $v \in V$ we have $y(v)$ $\in \ker((x-\lambda \text{Id}_V)^{\dim V }) $.

I need to show that it $v \in \ker ((x-\lambda \text{Id}_V)^{\dim v} )$, $y \in L$ then $(x-\lambda \text{Id}_V)^{\dim V } (yv)=0 $ but I just can’t make any headway after this.

Any pointers?

Comment: You can prove by induction on $n$ (for $n\ge 1$) that if $x\in I, y\in L$ then $[(x-\lambda I)^n, y] = n [x,y] (x-\lambda I)^{n-1}$ with $[x, y]\in I$.  Does that help?

Comment: I can see how that would help. I actually already know that for $x \in H, y \in L$ that we have $x^n y =n[x, y]x^{n-1} +yx^n $ but I tried replacing $x$ by $x-\lambda \text{Id}_V $ but I realised that the problem with this is that $x-\lambda \text{Id}_V $ is not in $I$. How can I use what I did already to get what you did?

Comment: The associative multiplication and bracket are in $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$, not just any Lie algebra.  $I$ commutes with everything, $[x,y]$ commutes with $x$ because both are in $I$ and $I$ is abelian.  In a Lie bracket of associative algebra you have an identity $[uv,w] = [u,w]v + u[v,w]$.  So the induction proof follows through.

Comment: I’m sorry I’m really confused what you’re trying to say. Can you clarify this a bit with some details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a proof of the formula in the comments.  I'll use $\mathbf{1}$ for the identity in $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ so as not to use $I$ which is the symbol for the ideal.

$$[x-\lambda \mathbf{1}, y] = [x, y] - \lambda [\mathbf{1}, y] = [x,y]$$
because $[\mathbf{1}, y] = 0$.

Assume by induction that
$$[(x-\lambda \mathbf{1})^n, y] = n[x,y](x-\lambda \mathbf{1})^{n-1}$$
then
$$\begin{align}
[(x-\lambda \mathbf{1})^{n+1}, y] &= [(x-\lambda \mathbf{1})(x-\lambda\mathbf{1})^{n}, y]\\
&=[x-\lambda \mathbf{1}, y](x-\lambda \mathbf{1})^{n} + (x-\lambda \mathbf{1})[(x-\lambda\mathbf{1})^{n}, y]\\
&=[x,y](x-\lambda\mathbf{1})^{n}+(x-\lambda\mathbf{1})n[x,y](x-\lambda \mathbf{1})^{n-1}\\
&=[x,y]((x-\lambda\mathbf{1})^{n} + n (x-\lambda\mathbf{1})^{n})\\
&=(n+1)[x,y](x-\lambda\mathbf{1})^{n}
\end{align}$$
where use was made that $[x,y], x\in I$ so they commute because $I$ is abelian (and so $[x,y], (x-\lambda\mathbf{1})$ also commute), and also the identity $[uv,w] = [u,w]v + u[v,w]$ in an associative algebra.

Comment: How do you deduce this identity from the one I have already shown: that if $x \in I $ and $y \in L$ then $x^n y =n[x, y]x^{n-1}+yx^n $? As I said this holds for $x \in I $ but $x-\lambda \text{Id}_V \in I $ (as it’s not even in $\mathfrak{sl}(V)$.

Comment: @Anonmath101: I don't see a way to deduce it.  It has to be proven from scratch using a similar induction.  Maybe if you expand the exponent using the binomial formula you can do it, but it just looks more complicated.  I haven't tried.

Comment: @Anonmath101: You can extend the identity you wrote by linearity to show that for any polynomial $f$, $[f(x), y] = [x,y]f'(x)$ where $f'(x)$ is the formal derivative.  For $(x-\lambda)^n$ the formal derivative is $n(x-\lambda)^{n-1}$ by the chain rule for formal derivative.